# Displaying additional profile fields that are synced with AD using JavaScript

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory, user-profile, spservices

Along with the thumbnail photo, I may want to display other properties in my master pages that are imported from AD such as "company" using User Profile sync

If I use SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser() (https://spservices.codeplex.com/documentation), I can get selected properties held in user profile settings.  However, I can't make this call since the property does not exist here (yet).

```
 var company = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
fieldName: "Company",
 debug: false
});
```

It is however,  is displayed both in http://mysite.mydomain.com/_layouts/EditProfile.aspx when in Mysite and _layouts/ProfAdminEdit.aspx (Edit user properties in Central Admin). I guess my question is then to be able to use SPServices, do I somehow edit the default properties and include my "Company" attribute held in the user' mysite profile? Alternatively, is there another way to access the properties held in the user profile with JavaScript ?

Thanks

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

$().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser calls this page : `http://you.site.com/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?Force=True&1376982818371`. For me the function is not able to parse the page correctly, but you could simply use jQuery (or pure JS or whatever) to get by yourself the same page, and then parse it to find the data you want.

Otherwise you can use [$SP().people()](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/symbols/%24SP%28%29.html#.people) to query the User Profile Service and gets the info for the user. See the example from the provided link. In theory that should return you the same information or even more info.